# Another proof question for real analysis

Tags: proof-writing

> Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove if $a + b = a$ then $b = 0$.

Suppose that $a + b = a$.  Then $a + b - a = a - a = 0 = b$ by the inverses law for addition. By the Identity law for addition it follows that $a + 0 = a$, and it follows by the Identity law for addition that if $b = 0$, then $0 + b = b = 0$, therefore $b = 0$.

Is it redundant to use the identity law for addition for a and b? Does this seem correct?

Comment: It's not redundant.

Comment: Here's an oddity about MathJax: As you'd expect, a hyphen in math tags looks like a minus sign and one not in math tags looks like a hyphen, thus: $a-a$ versus $a$-$a$.  BUT an actual minus sign in math tags looks like neither of the above, but rather like $a{-}a$. (I edited accordingly above.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Your second sentence (Stripped of some specifics: “By a law, it follows that ..., and it follows by another law, that if $b=0$ then $q$ therefore $b=0$”) is a bit wordy, and arguably not valid. Once you assume the if-part of the theorem, you must conclude the then-part (which is $b=0$). The red flag is that part of your demonstration contains “if $b=0$.” A statement of the form “if $b=0$” doesn’t belong in an argument that purports to *conclude* that $b=0$.